# JSON Parse error: unterminated string on React Native

Tags: json, react-native

I am receiving this error:

> JSON Parse error: unterminated string

my json is code:

```
[{"nomeEmpresa":"CACHORRO QUENTE E PASTEL DO ROMERO ", "nomeCategoria":"Alimentação", "subcategoria":"LANCHONETE", "email":"juniorromero116@gmail.com", "descricao":"Lanchonete Cachorro Quente e Pastel do Romero. Temos os mais saborosos lanches da cidade. Com uma excelente variedade em nosso cardápio, venha sentir o sabor. Tradição na cidade de Cupira desde 1993.", "endereco":"R. DOM JUVÊNCIO DE BRITO", "bairro":"CENTRO ", "wifi":"1", "cartao":"0", "delivery":"1", "horario":"SEGUNDA A SáBADO : 8:00 AS 12:00 E 14:00 AS 23:30 DOMINGO : 16:00 AS 00:00", "logo":"upload/8acf1595198096b1bb170ea10685243d.jpg", "imagens":[{"imagem":"upload/6480ca25e9a4237d7d0964d844e7ee7e.jpg", "titulo":"", "valor":""}, {"imagem":"upload/5e461acc9f2993c29794993ca7b9d742.jpg", "titulo":"", "valor":""}, {"imagem":"upload/c570e5df3146ece84eb600e300a2d7bd.jpg", "titulo":"", "valor":""}, {"imagem":"upload/2ded47256f054093b317f408fb4778d0.jpg", "titulo":"", "valor":""}], "sociais":[{"link":"https://www.facebook.com/cachorroquentedoromero/", "tipo":"0"}], "telefones":[{"ddd":"81", "numero":"99364-3465", "operadora":"3", "whatsapp":"1"}]}]
```

I receive this json accessing the url `https://buscafree.com.br/listaDetalhe.php?id=40`

If I access `https://buscafree.com.br/listaDetalhe.php?id=45` this works perfectly.

The error is solved if I delete the value of the descricao key:

```
Lanchonete Cachorro Quente e Pastel do Romero. Temos os mais saborosos lanches da cidade. Com uma excelente variedade em nosso cardápio, venha sentir o sabor. Tradição na cidade de Cupira desde 1993.
```

I can't understand why this error occurs, because this is a simple text.

My react native code is:

```
busca(categoria) {
  fetch(`https://buscafree.com.br/listaDetalhe.php?id=${categoria}`)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    this.setState({empresas:responseJson})
  })
  .catch((err) => this.setState({mensagem:{err}}))
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: @PritishVaidya >JSON Parse error: unterminated string

Comment: The error is due to the server returning `text/html` type of data, change that `json` for a correct response

Comment: @PritishVaidya this is a link that is receive the json `https://buscafree.com.br/listaDetalhe.php?id=40`

Comment: @PritishVaidya if I access with id=45, this works... very strange